# C#: How to access managed 2D array on the C++-CLI side?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c++-cli

How do I access a managed 2D array on the C++ side?

I know we are supposed to use `pin_ptr<T>` in order to access the managed array from the C++ side. It's straightforward with a 1D array, but with a 2D array I don't know how to use `pin_ptr<T>` correctly.

My code looks like this, where `foo()` will be called from the C# side:

```
nativeFunc(double **ptr);

foo(array<double,2> ^A)
{
    const int len = A->GetLength(0);
    double **ptr = (double**) alloca(sizeof(double*) * len);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
       pin_ptr<double> pinned = &A[i,0]; //Will go out of scope!
       ptr[i] = pinned;
    }

    nativeFunc(ptr);
}
```

The problem is that my `pin_ptr<T>` will go out of scope too early, as it's located inside the loop body, and thus I think above code is NOT safe. But how can I avoid this? Apparently, it's not allowed to make an array of `pin_ptr<T>`, neither managed nor unmanaged. It also cannot be added to a `std::vector` and it cannot be made a class member either. So I'm kind of stuck here...

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: For a 2D you need two for-loops (second loop replaces `ptr[i] = pinned;`). You're now pointing to scope-specific data (`pin_ptr<double> pinned`) from a long lasting unmanaged memory (`ptr`)

Comment: Why would I need *two* loops? With a **1D** array, I don't need a loop at all, because ``pin_ptr`` gives me an unmanaged pointer to the array data. With a **2D** array (i.e. array of arrays), I need the loop, because I need to iterate over the "outer" array and receive an unmanaged pointer to each "inner" array. The big problem is that ``pin_ptr`` only *pinns* the data until it goes out of scope - which is after each iteration of my loop... – If it wasn't clear, my goal is to get an unmanaged ``double**`` pointer to the array data, as the "native" function needs. I don't want to copy the data!

Comment: the data in `pin_ptr<double>` is valid as long as the `pin_ptr<double>` is in scope. In your code above, the scope ends at the next line (`}`), after which you're not allowed to read/write from/to the pointer. So: 1) You're perfectly allowed to edit data while `pin_ptr<double>` is alive. 2) to use the data after you dispose of `pin_ptr<double>`, you'll need to copy that data to your own memory (using a second for-loop; or a `memcpy`)

Comment: I'm well aware the data in `pin_ptr<double>` is valid as long as the `pin_ptr<double>` is in scope. And having to copy the data is what I want to avoid. That's the point. Anyway, I found in one of the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18132394.aspx) the following info: "Pinning a sub-object defined in a managed object has the effect of pinning the entire object. For example, if any element of an array is pinned, then the whole array is also pinned." So the  `pin_ptr<double>` can simply be **outside** of the loop to avoid the "out of scope" problem altogether!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some more digging, I found out that `GCHandle::Alloc(x, GCHandleType::Pinned)` may work as a more flexible replacement for `pin_ptr<T>` here. However, it seems we can only pin down the managed array as a whole. It does **not** seem to be possible to pin down a single sub-array (inner array) this way, like the `pin_ptr<T>` would do. Furthermore, by "try and error" method I have figured out that from the GCHandle handle I can get an *unmanaged* pointer via `hdl.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer()` and that this one points to a *continuous* block of memory which contains the whole **2D** array in a "flattened" (serialized) form. From here I can reconstruct the *unmanaged* 2D array, by using the proper base-pointer and stride. But is this considered a "safe" method and does it *always* work or is it even *implementation specific* ???

---

So I have hacked together a solution like this:

```
class ArrayPinHandlerRAII
{
public:
    ArrayPinHandlerRAII(array<double,2> ^managedArray)
    {
        m_dimOuter = managedArray->GetLength(0);
        m_dimInner = managedArray->GetLength(1);

        m_handle = GCHandle::Alloc(managedArray, GCHandleType::Pinned);
        m_ptr = new double*[m_dimOuter];
        double *basePointer = reinterpret_cast<double*>
            (m_handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer());

        for(size_t d = 0; d < m_dimOuter; d++)
        {
            m_ptr[d] = basePointer;
            basePointer += m_dimInner;
        }
    }

    ~ArrayPinHandlerRAII(void)
    {
        delete [] m_ptr;
        m_handle.Free();
    }

    inline double **data(void)
    {
        return m_ptr;
    }

    inline const size_t &dimOuter(void) const
    {
        return m_dimOuter;
    }

    inline const size_t &dimInner(void) const
    {
        return m_dimInner;
    }

private:
    GCHandle m_handle;
    double **m_ptr;
    size_t m_dimOuter;
    size_t m_dimInner;
};
```

***Any opinions? ;-)***

Comment: See my other answer for a better method!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one of the examples in MSDN has the following important info:

> Pinning a sub-object defined in a managed object has the effect of pinning the entire object. **For example, if any element of an array is pinned, then the whole array is also pinned.** There are no extensions to the language for declaring a pinned array. To pin an array, declare a pinning pointer to its element type, and pin one of its elements.

So the code can actually be simplified to:

```
void nativeFunc(double **ptr);

void foo(array<double,2> ^A)
{
    int dimOuter = managedArray->GetLength(0);
    int dimInner = managedArray->GetLength(1);

    pin_ptr<double> pinned = &A[i,0]; //This pins the *entire* array!

    double **ptr = (double**) alloca(sizeof(double*) * dimOuter); 
    double *basePtr = pinned;

    for(int i = 0; i < dimOuter; i++)
    {
       ptr[i] = basePtr;
       basePtr += dimInner;
    }

    nativeFunc(ptr);
}
```